# Custom styled attribute always set by default

Tags: android, android-styles

I have defined custom styled attribute for color..

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="custom1" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="custom2" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

When fetching attributes defined in xml through obtainStyledAttributes, it always returns size as 1, even if no attributes are defined in xml.

```
TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, 0, 0);
final int size = attributes.getIndexCount();

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    final int attr = attributes.getIndex(i);
    if (attr == R.styleable.CustomView_custom1) {
        boolean b = attributes.getBoolean(attr, false);
     }
    else if (attr == R.styleable.CustomView_custom2) {
        ColorStateList cs = attributes.getColorStateList(attr);
        int color = cs.getDefaultColor();
    }
}
```

Here size is always 1 even if no attribute defined in xml..
Because of that color gets some random value, not sure from where it is getting some value?

Output is as below:

```
Test﹕ ----
Test﹕ CustomView= 2130772048
Test﹕ CustomView= 2130772049
Test﹕ ----
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842901 textSize
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842904 textColor
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842927 gravity
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842960 id
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842966 paddingLeft
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842968 paddingRight
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842996 layout_width
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16842997 layout_height
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16843000 layout_marginTop
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16843101 singleLine
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16843119 drawableLeft
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16843121 drawablePadding
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 16843139 layout_toRightOf
Test﹕ AttributeSet= 2130772048 custom1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results.  Have you tried creating instances of CustomView with one and both attributes defined in the XML to see what `getIndexCount()` returns for those cases?

Comment: It always gets some value for color.. So when only custom1 is defined, it gets values for both custom1 and custom2.. When both custom1 and custom2 are defined, size is 2 and it fetches values correctly... When only custom2 is defined, size is 1 and only color value is fetched..

Comment: What class does your CustomView derive from ?

Comment: It derives from TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange problem. I can only suggest that you add debug log output and experiment with changes to get more visibility on what is going on.

These statements dump the attribute ids for your custom view and in the `AttributeSet` for the instance of your custom view in the layout XML.

```
Log.i("Test", "----");
for (int id : R.styleable.CustomView) {
    Log.i("Test", "CustomView= " + id);
}

Log.i("Test", "----");
int n = attrs.getAttributeCount();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Log.i("Test", "AttributeSet= " + attrs.getAttributeNameResource(i) + " " + attrs.getAttributeName(i));
}
```

To see if the `custom2` attribute is set in the theme or not:

```
TypedValue val = new TypedValue();
boolean resolved = context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.custom2, val, true);
if (resolved) {
    Log.i("Test", "Custom2 in theme");
} else {
    Log.i("Test", "Custom2 NOT in theme");
}
```

Comment: will try that.. meanwhile added another boolean custom3 and setting it false where I don't need default color values..

Comment: There is no custom2 in attributes.. but when obtainStyledAttributes is called it gets value for custom2 somehow.. please see output at the end of question..

Comment: If you post the entire block of code where you call `obtainStyledAttributes()` and operate on the `TypedArray`, I'll look it over.

Comment: It's pretty big class.. can't post entire class.. Just updated code how values are fetched.. maybe will create separate project later if required..

Comment: The code you posted looks correct.  The fact that `custom2` does not appear in the` AttributeSet` dump suggests it is coming from the theme set for the context being used.  Do you have any themes that define a value for `custom2`?

Comment: Thanks.. yes it was defined in one of the dependent libraries.. renaming it and it's solved now..

Comment: It was an interesting problem.  I learned a few things.  One final note:  If you aren't already doing so, be sure to recycle your `TypedArray` when done using it.  The [guide for creating a view class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) recommends using a try-finally block.

Comment: yes I always do that.. Another thing to keep in mind is to always use prefixes while naming attributes specially if it's a library to be used in multiple projects..

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was this:

```
  private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) { 
    post {
        val attributes = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomButton,
            0, 0
        )
        .....
```

if I get attributes in post{} it didn't get. This worked :

```
 private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
    val attributes = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.CustomButton,
        0, 0
    )
    post {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by using:

```
TypedArray attributes = context.applicationContext.obtainStyledAttributes()
```

instead of:

```
TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes()
```

No idea why, but it works!